# Replace a view with table entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, mapping

I have a table ***Employee*** and view ***vwEmployee***. *vwEmployee* do some processing and return a structure that is exacltly same as *Employee* table.

(this is beacuse some data in employee table is not valid and must replaced with some processing).

Now I create database first Entity Framework model and add *Employee* table to it, so In model I have *Employee entity* that is mapped to *Employee Table*. But i want it mapped to *vwEmployee* and get data from view.

I change mapping in *Mapping Details Window* but I get some compile time error

> Problem in mapping fragments starting at line  Missing table mapping:
>   Foreign key constraint 'FK_Employee_EmpTypes' from table Employee
>   (Emp_Type) to table EmpTypes (EmpType_No): no mapping specified for
>   the table Employee.

How can I fix this problem in *Employee* entity?